# streaming data from UWA to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Universal Windows Application in which I'm collecting Microsoft Band sensor data in real-time. Now I'd like to stream these sensor data to a WPF application. I originally thought that the AppServiceConnection class could be the best way to go, but I can't seem to understand how to use this communication process when I only want t real-time communication in which the service provider grabs the sensor data and continuously streams it, while the client receives and displays the data.

Here is some code:
Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;


namespace Socket_Communication_UWA
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {


        private StreamSocket clientSocket;
        private HostName serverHost;
        //private string serverHostnameString;
        //private string serverPort;
        private bool connected = false;
        private bool closing = false;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            clientSocket = new StreamSocket();
        }



        private async void connect(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (connected)
            {
                StatusText.Text = "Already connected";
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                OutputView.Text = "";
                StatusText.Text = "Trying to connect ...";

                serverHost = new HostName(ServerHostname.Text);
                // Try to connect to the 
                await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, ServerPort.Text);
                connected = true;
                StatusText.Text = "Connection established" + Environment.NewLine;

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // If this is an unknown status, 
                // it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
                if (Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                StatusText.Text = "Connect failed with error: " + exception.Message;
                // Could retry the connection, but for this simple example
                // just close the socket.

                closing = true;
                // the Close method is mapped to the C# Dispose
                clientSocket.Dispose();
                clientSocket = null;

            }
        }

        private async void Send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!connected)
            {
                StatusText.Text = "Must be connected to send!";
                return;
            }

            UInt32 len = 0; // Gets the UTF-8 string length.

            try
            {
                OutputView.Text = "";
                StatusText.Text = "Trying to send data ...";

                // add a newline to the text to send
                string sendData = SendText.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(clientSocket.OutputStream);
                len = writer.MeasureString(sendData); // Gets the UTF-8 string length.

                // Call StoreAsync method to store the data to a backing stream
                await writer.StoreAsync();

                StatusText.Text = "Data was sent" + Environment.NewLine;

                // await writer.FlushAsync();
                // writer.WriteString("go" + Environment.NewLine);
                // detach the stream and close it
                await writer.FlushAsync();
                writer.DetachStream();
                writer.Dispose();



                closing = true;
                clientSocket.Dispose();
                clientSocket = null;
                connected = false;

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // If this is an unknown status, 
                // it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
                if (Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    throw;
                }

                StatusText.Text = "Send data or receive failed with error: " + exception.Message;
                // Could retry the connection, but for this simple example
                // just close the socket.

                closing = true;
                clientSocket.Dispose();
                clientSocket = null;
                connected = false;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Listener:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace Socket_listener
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {



        string line;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public async void button_start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 port = 4510;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
            listener.Start();

            using (TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("This is the received message " + line);
                    //textBox.Text = line;
                    // client.Close();
                }
                //  Console.WriteLine("This is the received message " + line);

            }

            listener.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I implemented this using sockets. The client is a Universal Windows program and the server(listener) is a WPF and I thought that everything was fine. But when I went back to my code, I found out that something is wrong and it does not run anymore. I can't remember what I changed or figure out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SignalR lib for this. I have successfully used this with SCADA networks in conjunction with WPF and Web applications at the sametime.

You can find more information on this lib at: [SignalR Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignalR), [SignalR ASP.NET Site](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: Another great feature of this lib is that VS uses it for its "Browser Link" feature and more, so it is not going out of support anytime soon. It can also be used on almost any device even Raspberry Pi devices. I love this lib.

Comment: It doesn't work with Universal Windows Applications. I need to establish a communication channel between a WPF and a Universal Windows Application. The WPF is the client and the one managing everything. The UWA only acquires data from sensors and passes them along

Comment: What about a straight TCP/Socket connection? Or a Middleware Web api?